# Broken Magento 1.8 default product gallery

Tags: image, magento, gallery, magento-1.8

[Magento Website - Product](http://tugasunwear.com/plangea.com/girls/sets/three-piece-sets/surfer-girl.html)

I am fairly new to Magento and have been adding products into our catalog. I installed a theme and have made some adjustments via CSS.

I have also tinkered with adding extensions through Magento Connect, one of which was an improved "deep zoom" and other zoom-type galleries to replace the standard one. Unfortunately, somewhere along an uninstall the side thumbnails have lost their "Fixed area with scrolling" and now just pour down the page and into the description area.

I'm at a loss at how to fix this and don't want to rebuild the entire site.

Comment: I just checked your site.. All the images are displaying fine. Is the issue solved? If Yes, Please post your answer here and also why the product description and review tabs are displaying twice? Is there any issue with them??

Comment: Pavan, from my understanding, the images should only show 3-4 stacked at a time and scroll through, not all be displayed at once down the side of the page. I uninstalled some extensions I am not using anymore and now have lost the hover-zoom feature

Comment: No. There is no such an option in magento. I dont have knowledge on 1.8. But as of 1.7.0.2, there is no such an option. we need to customize it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual steps in this situation are:

a) Check that all the modules you added but are no longer using are uninstalled

b) System->configuration->advanced->advanced : if you see a module here that you thought you uninstalled, then it isn't uninstalled but you can just turn it off here anyway (later, ensure you remove at least the module's XML file from `app/etc/modules/`)

c) Ensure compilation is turned off System->tools->compilation

d) Refresh and / or turn off all caches including Magento Cache, Cache Storage, and Javascript/CSS cache

e) Reload the front page (ensure your browser isn't caching an old CSS file) and inspect the CSS to understand what is throwing the display off.

f) Check the local.xml of your theme for any errors but if you didn't edit that you should be okay.

g) Check for any HTML typing errors in, eg, the product description, which might throw out the page layout.

h) Check your browser console for any JavaScript errors: it may be that the thumbnail scrolling layout is set up via JavaScript but an error is stopping the formatting code running

Oh, check you aren't merging all the CSS and Javascript files too (system->Configuration->advanced->developer) and turn off Fooman Speedster if you are using that (or anything else that combines CSS at least until you find the glitch)

If it is still not displaying right, go back to the default Magento theme to at least know that it is due to your theme - if it is only due to your theme then re-installing the theme might help rather than a full application install.